# My outputs are not outputting any current at only two of my pinmodes but work fine on the others

Tags: arduino-uno, code-review

My pinMode output 5 and 6 don't works with this code but will work when they are stand alone.

What is causing the Arduino to not output anything from these outputs within my code?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>                    // use the software serial library
SoftwareSerial mySerial(3,4); // receive data at pin 3; transmit data at pin 2
int setpoint;
float val;
int roomtemp;
int UCL;
int LCL;

float salinity;
void setup()
{
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
    roomtemp=25;
    setpoint=7.0291*roomtemp+334.73;
    UCL=setpoint+6.12;
    LCL=setpoint-6.12;
    Serial.print("Setpoint =");
    Serial.print(setpoint);
    Serial.print("Degrees Celsius");
    Serial.print("UCL =");
    Serial.print(UCL);
    Serial.print("Degrees Celsius");
    Serial.print("LCL =");
    Serial.print(LCL);
    Serial.print("Degrees Celsius");
    mySerial.begin(9600);
    delay(500);           // set data rate to 9600 baud; wait for bootup
    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(128);
    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(1);    // clear screen & move to top left position
    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(132);
    mySerial.print("LCL");
    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(139);
    mySerial.print("SP");
    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(144);
    mySerial.print("UCL");
    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(192);
    mySerial.print("S:");
    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(195);
    mySerial.print(0.072,3);
    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(201);
    mySerial.print(0.100,3);
    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(207);
    mySerial.print(0.108,3);
    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(148);
    mySerial.print("T:");
    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(152);
    mySerial.print("24.1");
    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(158);
    mySerial.print("25.0");
    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(164);
    mySerial.print("25.9");
    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(212);
    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(212);
    mySerial.print("S=");
    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(220);
    mySerial.print("T=");
}

void loop()
{
    Serial.println();
    int val=analogRead(5);
    Serial.print("Analog Value =");
    Serial.print(val);
    Serial.print("Temperature =");
    Serial.println((0.14227*val)-47.621);

    if(val<LCL) { digitalWrite(3,HIGH); }
    else if(val>UCL) { digitalWrite(3,LOW); }

    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(227);

    if(val<LCL) { mySerial.write("H= ON"); }

    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(227);

    if(val>UCL) { mySerial.write("H=OFF"); }

    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    int analogS=analogRead(4);
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    Serial.println(analogS);
    delay(1000);
    salinity = 2.0955*pow(10,-19)*pow(analogS,5.8106)*100.000;
    Serial.print("Salinity =");
    Serial.println(salinity);
    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(214);
    mySerial.print(salinity);
    mySerial.write(254);
    mySerial.write(222);
    mySerial.print((0.14227*val)-47.621,1);
    Serial.println("analog value");
    Serial.print(analogRead(4));
    float target= (salinity-(salinity-.1)*.60);
    float numer=((((target)*.08585-(salinity)*.08585)/(.1-(.1*.15+salinity*.85)))*60.0);
    float denom= ((.1));
    float valve= ((numer/denom)/10.00);

    if(.096<salinity>.104) {
        delay(5000);
    }

    if(salinity>.104) {
        Serial.print("Entering DIon Function");
        digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
        delay(valve);
        digitalWrite(6,LOW);
        delay(5000);
    }

    if(salinity<.096) {
        Serial.print("Entering Saltyon Function");
        digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
        delay(valve);
        digitalWrite(5,LOW);
        delay(5000);
    }

    Serial.print("time");
    Serial.println(valve);
}
```

Comment: So you are sure that the code parts in which a `digitalWrite` with 5 or 6 pin is executed, but you don't see the pin values chaning? Can you print out the value of `valve`, too, or put more delay after setting it HIGH?

Comment: And what is printed out to serial monitor?

Comment: What does `if(.096<salinity>.104) ` evaluate (in plain english)?

Comment: @Juraj `analogRead(5)` selects the same ADC pin as `analogRead(A5)`, which is the same as `analogRead(19)`. (Even `analogRead(13)` will work). As it will [subtract 14 if the value is bigger or equal to 14](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_analog.c#L54), and only use the lower 3 bits.

Comment: @Gerben, yes I remembered and deleted the comment (somehow wrong, because it is still there :-) )

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not in the output pin (which you say works elsewhere) but in your calculations. I made a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the part of the code that does the calculations, testing every possible reading you might have got from `analogRead(4)` (mainly because I found the calculations code rather obscure). Here it is:

```c++
float salinity;
void setup()
  {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  }

void loop()
  {
  for (int analogS=0; analogS < 1024; analogS++)
    {
    Serial.print ("analogS = ");
    Serial.print (analogS);
    salinity = 2.0955*pow(10,-19)*pow(analogS,5.8106)*100.000;
    Serial.print (", Salinity = ");
    Serial.print (salinity);
    float target= (salinity-(salinity-.1)*.60);
    float numer=((((target)*.08585-(salinity)*.08585)/(.1-(.1*.15+salinity*.85)))*60.0);
    float denom= ((.1));
    float valve= ((numer/denom)/10.00);
    Serial.print(",  valve = ");
    Serial.println(valve);
    }
   Serial.flush ();
   exit (1);
  }
```

Testing that reveals:

```
analogS = 0, Salinity = 0.00,  valve = 3.64
analogS = 1, Salinity = 0.00,  valve = 3.64
analogS = 2, Salinity = 0.00,  valve = 3.64
analogS = 3, Salinity = 0.00,  valve = 3.64
... some lines omitted ...
analogS = 1016, Salinity = 6.21,  valve = 3.64
analogS = 1017, Salinity = 6.25,  valve = 3.64
analogS = 1018, Salinity = 6.28,  valve = 3.64
analogS = 1019, Salinity = 6.32,  valve = 3.64
analogS = 1020, Salinity = 6.35,  valve = 3.64
analogS = 1021, Salinity = 6.39,  valve = 3.64
analogS = 1022, Salinity = 6.43,  valve = 3.64
analogS = 1023, Salinity = 6.46,  valve = 3.64
```

As you can see, `valve` is always 3.64, so you will be doing this:

```c++
    digitalWrite(6,HIGH);
    delay(3);
    digitalWrite(6,LOW);
```

In other words, port 6 will be HIGH for 3 milliseconds, probably too short a time for you to notice. Ditto for port 5.

---

Also this doesn't do what I suspect you think it does:

```
if(.096<salinity>.104) {
    delay(5000);
}
```

That will evaluate `.096 < salinity` to be 0 or 1. Then it will evaluate:

```
0 > 0.104
1 > 0.104
```

This is not what you are intending, I think. Try:

```
if(salinity < .096 || salinity > .104) {
    delay(5000);
}
```

If that is what you mean, I can't be sure - maybe you mean the opposite:

```
if(salinity > .096 && salinity < .104) {
    delay(5000);
}
```

If you write things out clearly, without trying to do shortcuts, it will be much more obvious what the test really is.

Comment: When I first saw `.096<salinity>.104` I thought it was a oscure new C++ feature, like a range validator operand. So neat: is `salinity` in this range? But no, ii means another thing. BTW, Java doesn't accept such expression, because it compares a boolean with a float. The problem with C/C++ is too much power for the unexperienced guy. Think of you trying to debug a program like these. C/C++ is full of traps.

Comment: I don't mean to demean the OP, whom is just a beginner, but the many C/C++ pitfalls.

Comment: I think Cobol used to work like that, however that is pretty old. :)